# error when close with effect fade window pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a bit when try change new window UI with effect fade. I added effect on closeEvent of mainwindow but it doen't work.

This is my code:

library used:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic
```

## load ui

```
uifile_1 = 'home.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)

uifile_2 = 'plate.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)
```

## Class Home page:

```
class HomePage(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        #add button for click next page
        self.btn_start = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.change)

        self._heightMask = self.height()
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b"heightPercentage")
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)
        self.animation.setStartValue(self.height())
        self.animation.setEndValue(-1)
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.isStarted = False

    def change(self):
        self.plate = PlatePage()
        self.plate.show()
        self.close()

    @pyqtProperty(int)
    def heightMask(self):
        return self._heightMask

    @heightMask.setter
    def heightPercentage(self, value):
        self._heightMask = value
        rect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.heightMask)
        self.setMask(QRegion(rect))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.isStarted:
            self.animation.start()
            self.isStarted = True
            event.ignore()
        else:   
            self.closeEvent(self, event)
```

## Class Plate Page

```
class PlatePage(base_2, form_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
```

Please have a look and give me some solution.

Thank You

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: the links are backup, the important information should not depend on external links because if the question is broken it would not make sense for future readers. please read [ask] and review the [tour].

Comment: sorry for edit many time, the first post so i have some problem. Sorry again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QPropertyAnimation, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Button', self))

        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1000)        
        self.isStarted = False 

        self.doShow()

    def doShow(self):
        try:
            self.animation.finished.disconnect(self.close)
        except:
            pass

        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if not self.isStarted:
            self.animation.stop()
            self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)  
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
            self.animation.start()
            self.isStarted = True
            event.ignore()
        else:
            event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]